# Issues with running node install commands on terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WYKu.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL1W5.jpg)I've been trying to connect to my project server for the past week and every time I run into a new error. This time I'm having issues when I run the `npm install` command.

I get an exit status of

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
```

I get this message as a final error:

```
Failed at the v8-debug@0.7.7 install script, This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have added an image of the entire error logs I run into
[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL1W5.jpg)

[Error logs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQq5b.jpg)

New error images:
[new error log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCuFH.jpg)

[new error log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6KND.jpg)

Comment: Please provide the error message and whatever other detail you can. All you've told us is that npm install failed, which could happen for an infinite number of reasons.

Comment: @seesharper I have added 2 images of the error logs I recieved

Comment: Looks like you may need Xcode installed.

Comment: @seesharper I have it installed, but I keep on getting similar errors :( (check for new error log pics)

Comment: These look like classic version problems, which are sadly common in the npm ecosystem. You should check which version of node you are using and whether or not it is supported by all the packages you are installing. Too late or too early a version of node will lead to all sorts of chaos. I recommend using nvm or similar so you can switch versions at will.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting node_modules folder and then run the command npm install. If that does not solve the problem, check if you can run any other command through npm successfully. Try this command:
npx create-react-app "my-app"
and see if that works.

Comment: I tried moving the node_modules folder, but that didn't change a thing. I tried the "npx create-react-app "my-app"" command, and that connected me to the reactapp server, but when I try running 'npm install' command, I still get the same issues. I've attached an image with the respective error logs.

Comment: Your node seems to be having issues. Try removing your node and install a fresh copy and use latest stable version instead of the beta. Is this the first time you're using node?